# Sort a data.table fast by Ascending/Descending order

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I have a data.table with about 3 million rows and 40 columns. I would like to sort this table by descending order within groups like the following sql mock code:

```
sort by ascending Year, ascending MemberID, descending Month
```

Is there an equivalent way in data.table to do this? So far I have to break it down into 2 steps:

```
setkey(X, Year, MemberID)
```

This is very fast and takes only a few second.

```
X <- X[,.SD[order(-Month)],by=list(Year, MemberID)]
```

This step takes so much longer (5 minutes).

Update:
Someone made a comment to do `X <- X[sort(Year, MemberID, -Month)]` and later deleted. This approach seems to be much faster:

```
user  system elapsed 
5.560  11.242  66.236
```

My approach: setkey() then order(-Month)

```
   user  system elapsed 
816.144   9.648 848.798
```

My question is now: if I want to summarize by Year, MemberId and Month after sort(Year, MemberID, Month), does data.table recognize the sort order?

Update 2: to response to Matthew Dowle:

After setkey with Year, MemberID and Month, I still have multiple records per group. What I would like is to summarize for each of the groups. What I meant was: if I use X[order(Year, MemberID, Month)], does the summation utilizes binary search functionality of data.table:

```
monthly.X <- X[, lapply(.SD[], sum), by = list(Year, MemberID, Month)]
```

Update 3: Matthew D proposed several approaches. Run time for the first approach is faster than order() approach:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  7.910   7.750  53.916
```

Matthew: what surprised me was converting the sign of Month takes most of the time. Without it, setkey is blazing fast.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

#### Update June 5 2014:

The current development version of data.table v1.9.3 has two new functions implemented, namely: `setorder` and `setorderv`, which does exactly what you require. These functions reorder the `data.table` *by reference* with the option to choose either ascending or descending order on each column to order by. Check out `?setorder` for more info.

In addition, `DT[order(.)]` is also by default optimised to use `data.table`'s *internal fast order* instead of `base:::order`. This, unlike `setorder`, will make an entire copy of the data, and is therefore less memory efficient, but will still be orders of magnitude faster than operating using base's order.

#### Benchmarks:

Here's an illustration on the speed differences using `setorder`, data.table's internal fast order and with `base:::order`:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.3
set.seed(1L)
DT <- data.table(Year     = sample(1950:2000, 3e6, TRUE), 
                 memberID = sample(paste0("V", 1:1e4), 3e6, TRUE), 
                 month    = sample(12, 3e6, TRUE))

## using base:::order
system.time(ans1 <- DT[base:::order(Year, memberID, -month)])
#   user  system elapsed 
# 76.909   0.262  81.266 

## optimised to use data.table's fast order
system.time(ans2 <- DT[order(Year, memberID, -month)])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.985   0.030   1.027

## reorders by reference
system.time(setorder(DT, Year, memberID, -month))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.585   0.013   0.600 

## or alternatively
## setorderv(DT, c("Year", "memberID", "month"), c(1,1,-1))

## are they equal?
identical(ans2, DT)    # [1] TRUE
identical(ans1, ans2)  # [1] TRUE
```

On this data, benchmarks indicate that data.table's order is about **~79x faster** than `base:::order` and `setorder` is **~135x faster** than `base:::order` here.

`data.table` always sorts/orders in C-locale. If you should require to order in another locale, only then do you need to resort to using `DT[base:::order(.)]`.

All these new optimisations and functions together constitute [FR #2405](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2405&group_id=240&atid=978). [bit64::integer64 support also has been added](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/703).

---

> **NOTE:** Please refer to the history/revisions for earlier answer and updates.

Comment: @AdamNYC NP. You seem to writing `sort` when you mean `order`? Binary search is to do with `i` not `by`, so I'm not sure what you mean in the edit. I don't think it will be slow, and what you're doing seems correct.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. I corrected my update. Your explanation is clear.

Comment: @AdamNYC Ok but 66s feels slow. Do try option 1, just for completeness.

Comment: Hi Matthew, I updated my question per your suggestion. BTW, I can't thank you enough for such a terrific package.

Comment: @AdamNYC Hm. That 53s looks odd, given the 7s user time.  How did you time that and what exactly did you time?  A vector 3 million long should change sign quicker than that.

Comment: Hi Matt, here is the code I use. My table has 120 variables though `>   system.time({
     c[, Month := -Month];
     setkey(c, Year, MemberID, Month);
     c[, Month := -Month]
     }
    )
   user  system elapsed 
  7.910   7.750  53.916`

Comment: @AdamNYC thanks but that doesn't tally with what you wrote as edit to question.  How much is most?

Comment: Hi Matt, I'll time the assignment call shortly. I ran it before and it feels long. :-)

Comment: Sorry, my bio-clock didn't work: here is the breakdown of each step:` reverse sign:
   user  system elapsed 
  0.021   0.019   0.059 


setkey:
   user  system elapsed 
  7.842   7.411  48.878 
`

Comment: @AdamNYC  I might have an inkling why that is. Have raised [FR#2419 fastorder should iterate left to right](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2419&group_id=240&atid=978) to remind me to come back to it. Glad it wasn't the sign change after all, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Matthew. I am totally converted to data.table now.

Comment: @MatthewDowle Would it be possible to add the ability to set the sort order as descending in `setkey`?  For example, option 1.b would simply be `setkey(X,Year,MemberID,-Month)`.

Comment: @dnlbrky `setkey` is ascending order always I'm afraid and that's set in stone (relied on in binary search to keep things manageable internally). I was just about to suggest `data.table:::fastorder` but that takes column names not `-Month` unfortunately.

Comment: @MattDowle Is this answer still up-to-date? There does not seem to be much difference between `base:::order()` and `data.table:::forderv()` today. Am I wrong? (Tested on vectors, not on data frames.)

Comment: @arthur The answer indeed needs updating. data.table's sort code was included in R 3.3.0 released May 2016.

Answer (score 16):

The comment was mine, so I'll post the answer. I removed it because I couldn't test whether it was equivalent to what you already had. Glad to hear it's faster.

```
X <- X[order(Year, MemberID, -Month)]
```

Summarizing shouldn't depend on the order of your rows.