# How to wrap "descending sort in data table" into a function?

Tags: r, data.table

After seeing [Sort a data.table fast by Ascending/Descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685295/descending-sort-in-data-table-and-speed)

I would like to wrap either

```
X <- X[order(Year, MemberID, -Month)]
```

or

```
X[,Month:=-Month]
setkey(X,Year,MemberID,Month)
X[,Month:=-Month]
```

Into a function, like `d.setkey(data, key)`

However, seems `order` and `:=` rhs only accept column names instead of character, I don't know how I can pass argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `get`:

```
DT[, "Month" := -get("Month"),with=TRUE]
```

Or :

```
DT[,`:=`("Month"=-get("Month"))]
```

Or more general using an expression:

```
expr <- substitute(x := -x,  list(x=as.name("Month")))
DT[,eval(expr)]
```

Comment: why i cannot use `DT[,Month:=-as.name("Month")]`?

Comment: because you cannot do `-as.name("Month")`. (Not related to data.table here)

Comment: you can also do `DT[, "Month" := -eval(as.name("Month"))]` in 1.8.11 (and this is much more efficient than `get`, as the latter constructs *all* columns from `DT`)

Comment: @eddi what does  "constructs all columns" mean? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @colinfang `data.table` generally tries to understand the j-expression and figure out what columns are used and only internally populates those columns to do further operations with, like grouping (I'm actually not 100% sure it does that when there is no by). Unfortunately that logic goes out of the door the moment `get` or `.SD` are used, which is why those should generally be avoided if speed is a consideration. I actually added a FR today motivated by this question to internally replace get.