# Doing absolute descending sort of data.table through function?

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

I would like to do an **absolute descending sort** (i.e. sort ignoring sign so e.g. 5, -2, 1) of my `data.table` by passing a sort.field into a function.

I have looked at [descending sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929593/how-to-wrap-descending-sort-in-data-table-into-a-function?lq=1),  but in my efforts I get errors or I am transforming the sign of my variable, and not sorting it properly.

This works:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(id = c("a","b","z"), 
                 score = c(1, 5, -2))
DT1 <- copy(DT)

#doing sort direct works
DT1 <- DT1[order(-abs(score))] 
# i.e. b, Z, a
```

But when passing a parameter I cannot find the right syntax (math errors, j must be provided, etc.)

```
#in function
sort.field = "score"

sortme <- function(dt, sort.field){

  dt <- dt[order(-abs(sort.field))]  
}

DT2 <- sortme(DT, sort.field)
#  ERROR get non-numeric argument to maths function as it sees string
```

I have tried various evals, as.name, with = F, etc.

```
   dt <- dt[, order(-abs(as.name(sort.field))]  

   # even
    expr <- substitute(x := -abs(x),  list(x=as.name(sort.field)))
    dt<- dt[,eval(expr)]

DT3 <- DT[,eval(expr)] # changes all to negative
DT4 <- DT[order(eval(expr))] # DT not happy
```

Please put me out of my misery! Thanks so much.

P.S. `setorderv()` handles straight Ascending and Descending cases. Yes, I could add a column, absolute it and then use setorderv, then delete the temp column,  but I am looking for a *more elegant solution*.

**Edit:** Others have pointed to the similar [answer for filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564002/filter-data-table-by-dynamic-column-name). That question also covers data.frames, and not solely data tables, and is focused on filtering rows of data. It does not do a transformative ordering with a function like `abs()` of the field text, keeping all the rows and not changing the data. Also this question could help others looking at this absolute sort type for `data.table` which is not covered in its `setorderv()`.

Comment: Similar question, identical answers (and answerers) over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564002/filter-data-table-by-dynamic-column-name

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variably selecting/assigning to fields in a data.table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/variably-selecting-assigning-to-fields-in-a-data-table)

Comment: Thanks Frank for linking answers. I did not see these when I searched. You will see I tried the `with = FALSE`. My error was reassigning the data table and not just searching by ref - so should have avoided DT <- DT[..] when ordering. My answer is different as I am trying to put a function on colname which is  a bit trickier and I hope this answer will help others..

Comment: For what it's worth, I see all of these questions as the same because they all involve passing a string column name (or vector of names) for evaluation inside a `[.data.table` call. Whether it's in the `i` or `j` field; what the particular operation is; or whether you ask that it be turned into a function doesn't change the core of the question and answer. I'm fine with it not being voted a dupe, but I think there's a pretty good case. I hope when someone comes by asking for "case-independent sort" of a string column, `DT[order(upper(v))]`, we can mark that as a dupe with this at least.

Comment: I appreciate your sentiments. Getting to grips with `data.table` as a beginner can be tricky given how sophisticated the package is. When do you use `as.name()`, when do you use `with = F`, its no wonder the FAQ starts "why DT[, 5] returns 5!".  Beginners might also not realise that *variable selecting* = *putting through function* = *parameterising* are similar, although this is probably obvious to full time coders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sort.field = "score"

sortme <- function(dt, sort.field) dt[order(-abs(dt[[sort.field]]))]

sortme(DT, sort.field)
#   id score
#1:  b     5
#2:  z    -2
#3:  a     1
```

What you did after the first function definition was to pass a string to the `abs` function, hence the `ERROR get non-numeric argument to maths function as it sees string`

Answer (score 3):

The `eval(as.name())` would work

```
 sort.field = "score"
 sort_me <- function(dt, sort.field){
  dt[order(-abs(eval(as.name(sort.field))))]
 }
 sort_me(DT, sort.field)
 #   id score
 #1:  b     5
 #2:  z    -2
 #3:  a     1
```