# Can you sort descending using keyby =?

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

I would like to subset, use an aggreate function, AND sort (**descending**) my table `mytable` with 1 short statement. For example, I am counting rows with price > 100 grouped by color, and sorting this by color **descending**.
I have:

```
mytable2 <- mytable[price > 100, .N, by = color]
mytable2[order(-color)]
```

But I would rather have it be in one step. Something like:

```
mytable[price > 100, .N, keyby = color]
```

But this is *ascending*. Simply putting a `-` in front of color gives an error. Is there another way? Thanks.

Comment: Did you read [Sort a data.table fast by Ascending/Descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685295/sort-a-data-table-fast-by-ascending-descending-order) ?

Comment: I too would like to find out if possible because while `mytable2[order(-color)]` works a `keyby` solution wouldn't necessitate chaining. More succinct

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [chaining](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-intro.html#c-chaining-1) commands of `data.table`?
Something like the below should serve the purpose of  having it in one  step.

```
> library(data.table)
> mytable <- data.table(price = seq(50,150,10), 
+                       color = sample(x= c("Red","Green","Blue"),size = 11,replace = T))
> 
> mytable[ price > 100,.SD ,by = .(color)][order(-color)]
   color price
1:   Red   110
2:   Red   130
3: Green   120
4: Green   150
5:  Blue   140
> ## As Color is a character variable it will be (reversely) sorted alphabatically.
```